# AngularJS use a global scope function inside another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I have the following AngularJS function called `editlocation` that opens a Modal window that I can edit three pieces of data.

After the result I want to be able to run `plotmarkers` this is used in another instance of an `ng-click`. I have tried the following but it doesn't work. I also tried placing it inside the `ModalInstanceCtrl2` controller too, but no luck.

```
$scope.editlocation = function (locations) {
    var locationToEdit = locations; 
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'template/modal-edit-marker.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl2,
        resolve: {
            locations: function () {
                return locationToEdit;
            }
        },
        scope: $scope.$new()
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    locationToEdit.title = selectedItem.title;
    locationToEdit.gps = selectedItem.gps;
    locationToEdit.desc = selectedItem.desc;
    $scope.plotmarkers;
    }, function () {
        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};


$scope.plotmarkers = function() {
    //things will happen here
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually calling the function here. Try this:

```
$scope.plotmarkers();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless plotmarkers in in the same controller/scope (ModalInstanceCtrl2) you are calling it that won't work. a far better approach would be to emit or broadcast an event that would let know every interested party that markers should be plotted you can do it either using the controllers scope or the $rootScope if you have it injected.

Comment: excuse me why was i down voted here? whats wrong with my answer? if someone could please educate me in what is wrong with my method, we might all learn something in the process